# Why does audio and video stop when I fast forward in a MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, amazon-fire-tv

I am working on a media streaming application. I am working on Fire TV Android version 5.0.

I am having a strange problem. When I seek video to forward, my video frame gets stuck and audio plays only for 10-15 seconds and after that audio also gets stuck.

I have checked the logs and received the following exception :

```
I/AudioFlinger( 8622): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0x42375008
```

i am simple using

```
 videoview.seekTo(position);
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please always post a small snippet of code to demonstrate how you actually fast forward and where.

Comment: @Levon Thanks for edit. i am simple using videoview.seekTo(position);

Comment: Thanks nitin, however more info is needed: are you using the VisualOn SDK; what is the format/encoding of your video and audio; does the bitrate change in the stream while it's playing; does duration and start time on the higher and lower bitrate chunks align across different bitrates; is audio the same format across all bitrates?